# Force JNLP file to update itself

Tags: java, jnlp

This question has been asked before here in many different ways but without a satisfactory answer.

I have made some changes to my JNLP file, which is being used by hundreds of people. As I don't want them all to clear the cache on their local machine (not everyone has strong computer knowledge), I would like the JNLP file to get updated the next time they click on the link to launch the application.
How can I then force the client to download the JNLP file whenever that file changes?

Using JNLP attribute `href` or `codebase` is not an option since many of the users have bookmarked the link to the JNLP file.

Comment: `<update check="always" policy="always"/>` will download the files if they have changed...

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't have that line in my jnlp file and the new version of the file does in fact contain update check. The question is, how do I get the client machine to update its jnlp file without clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Last-Modified header did solve the problem.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19118631/243373) has some more information on that.